# Angular reactive form binding not working

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create nested reactive forms here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgrfbj

This is the project heirarchy:

```
---create company form (hello.component.ts)
    --- company details form (company-details.component.ts)
    --- [
        employee details form (employee-details.component.ts)
        employee details form
        employee details form ...
        ]
```

For such nested forms, I have to use `ViewProviders` and `FormGroupDirective` as given in [this video](https://youtu.be/CD_t3m2WMM8?t=2129):

The first nested form (*company-details.component.ts*) is working as expected

But the second form which is added with `*ngFor` inside a `FormArray` is not binding to the `FormGroupDirective` correctly.

When you type the company details and press **Print Json**, then the printed json will be correct. But when you add an employee or two, then the employee details are not printed in the json.

I know there are other manual ways to accomplish the same thing, but I'm looking for a clean solution that just works without any extra functions.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you notice that `this.fgd` is undefined in your employee-details ?

Comment: can you describe a little bit more about 'clean solution'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are to make several changes in your code

1.-The employed.details.component.html

```
<!---see that is [formGroup], not formGroupName-->
<div [formGroup]="employee">
  <h4 class="row">Employee no. {{index+1}}</h4>
  <div class='col-md-8'>
    <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <div class='col-md-8'>
    <input formControlName="planet" placeholder="Planet">
  </div>
</div>
```

2.- the employed.details.component.ts, becomes as

```
  employee: any;
  @Input() index;
  //inject the ForumGroupDirective in the variable fgd    
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private fgd: FormGroupDirective) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //get the FormArray of "employees"
    const array=(this.fgd.form.get('employees') as FormArray);

    //Simple push to the array
    array.push(this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      planet: ''
      }));
    //the formGroup must be array.at(index)
    this.employee = array.at(this.index)
  }
```

Finally, when remove the employe you must remove the element in the array

```
  removeEmployee() {
    this.employeesCount -= 1;
    (this.form.get('employees') as FormArray).removeAt(this.employeesCount);
  }
```

see the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6yd87?file=src%2Fapp%2Femployee-details%2Femployee-details.component.ts)

Comment: Saved my day! Also got to know about the reactive forms in more depth! Thank you so much!