# How to pass reactive form data between child to parent components with out using services

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular7

We would like to consume child reactive form data from parent when we click on parent button. Currently we are using viewchild for getting the child cpomponent reference. We are getting all static data but not the form filled data.......................................................................................................

```
parent.component.ts
@ViewChild(DetailsComponent) childrenComponent: childrenComponent;

save(){
let model=this.childrenComponent.buildDetailsModel();
/*here api to save model*/
}
children.component.ts
buildDetailsModel(): Details {
var a = {
  reportedToId: this.detailsForm.get('reportedTo').value,
  reportedOn: this.detailsForm.get('reportedTime').value,
  identifiedById: this.detailsForm.get('identifiedBy').value,
  identifiedOn: this.detailsForm.get('dateAndTimeIdentified').value,
  locationTypeId: this.detailsForm.get('locationType').value,
  addressId: this.detailsForm.get('locationAddress').value,
  AddressLine: this.detailsForm.get('locationOfAddress').value,
  description: this.detailsForm.get('description').value,
  PeopleExposed: this.dataSource
  };
  return a;
}

parent.html 
<child></child>

child.html
<form [formGroup]="detailsForm">
  <div fxLayout="column wrap" fxLayoutGap="12px">

    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayout.lt-md="column" 
   fxLayoutGap="24px">

      <div fxFlex="row" fxLayoutGap="24px" fxLayout.lt-md="column">
        <div fxFlex="column">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Reported To</mat-label>
            <mat-select matInput formControlName="reportedTo">
              <mat-option value="Test 1">Test 1</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="Test 2">Test 1</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>


          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="reportedTime" placeholder="Date 
          and time reported" date="true" time="true" 
          formControlName="reportedTime">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="reportedTime"></mat- 
           datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #reportedTime></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Identified by</mat-label>
            <mat-select matInput formControlName="identifiedBy">
              <mat-option value="Test 1">Test 1</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="Test 2">Test 1</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you share your html code as well.

Comment: can you check once

Answer (score 2):

If use a "referenceVariable" you will have access to all the public variables and functions of the "child"

```
<button (click)="click(mychild)"></button>
<child #mychild></child>

click(mychild.any)
{
   console.log(mychild.detailsForm);
}
```

Anyway, I think you want a child that belongs to a Form. For this, you can use viewProviders in child.

```
viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: FormGroupDirective
    }
  ]
```

As this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739013/angular-reactive-form-binding-not-working/53740436#53740436) show

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your child form Inside form element so that you can submit your child form from parent, Then Inject FormGroupDirective in child component to get ref of parent form

```
<form (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="detailsForm"> 
    <app-child></app-child>
    <button type="button">Save</button>
 </form>
```

Then use controlContainer to provide the existing FormGroupDirective in child component

**childcomponent.ts**

```
  form;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, @Host() private parentFor: FormGroupDirective) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.parentFor.form;
    //Add FormControl as per your need
    this.form.addControl('child', this.fb.group({
      name: "",
      email: ""
    }))

  }
```

**child.component.html**

```
<form formGroupName="child">
  <input formControlName="name">
  <input formControlName="email">
</form>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xusdev

Comment: This is working.. But how can i get Other properties(other than form fields)? Since we are using reactive form fields and template driven forms fields too in child component.