# angular passing input to child components in ng-content

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to pass some properties from a parent component to a child component using content projection, is that possible?

For e.g. this is my template:

```
<my-form [display]="'horiz'">
  Email: <my-input [type]="'email'" ...></my-input>
  Name: <my-input [type]="'name'" [display]="'vert'" ...></my-input>
  ...
</my-form>
```

Now the `my-form` component has the template like this:

```
<form ...>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>
```

What I want is that the `display` property of `my-form` can be accessed by the `my-input` components, such that it can be overriden by the `my-input` component as well, like it is for the Name input.

Is that possible?

Comment: I think [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SJ9Ch8jX3A) will help you!

Comment: do you want to overwrite the form value from my-inpu component?

Comment: @Chellappan yes, if my-input has a value, it should be used, and if not then the one from my-form should be used.

Comment: May be this link will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53946907/how-to-pass-reactive-form-data-between-child-to-parent-components-with-out-using/53948326#53948326

Comment: @PrashantPimpale the video explains the use of content projection but not helpful in what I asked in the question. Can you please point to the exact part in the video that you think should help... thanks!

Comment: @Chellappan tried the `FormGroupDirective` to access the parent form attributes but does not work. Do you know about a working example?

Comment: can you create a example in stackblitz

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `@ContentChildren` , made an example on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-content-children-example

I have modified the values in the `ngAfterViewInit` using the component references from the `ContentChildren`.

Hope it helps. Feel free to update the code if any better approach is there.

Comment: This is some nasty way to do that but it actually seems to work :D... is there a possibility that it can work for all types of components and not just `GrandChildComponent`? thanks btw
I mean if I have more than one types of components, like `my-input`, `my-select`, etc.

Comment: I think that can be done as well by making a `@ContentChildren` for each type of component and then loop on all of them. Right?

Comment: That would be one way to do it. Another way can be to add a custom directive to each element in the app-component and use that in the content children. You can use the `{read : <tokenType>}` to read `read a different token from the queried elements.`

Comment: I am not very much familiar with custom directives, can you put that in the example please. Although what I was looking for is achieved already. Thanks for that.