# Angular: reactive form controls not detected when ng build --prod excecuted

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a reactive form using Angular. In my template I've declared the `formControlName` attribute and have given names to them, and in the .ts component I have declared them too as `formControls`, members of a `FormGroup`, however, when I execute `ng build --prod`, I get an error saying they don't exist in the .ts.

this is my form:

```
 <form ngNativeValidate [formGroup]="forma" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
      <div class="row doc-row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <!-- Fecha desde-->
          <label class="col-sm-1 control-label lh-11 documento-label">Fecha desde</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="date" formControlName="fechaDesde" name="fechaDesde" id="fechaDesde" type="date"
              class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <span #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker class="fa fa-search facturas col-sm-1 " [(bsValue)]="fechaDesde"></span>

          <!-- Fecha hasta-->
          <label class="col-sm-1 control-label lh-11 documento-label">Fecha hasta</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="date" formControlName="fechaHasta" name="fechaHasta" id="fechaHasta" type="date"
              class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <em #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker class="fa fa-search facturas col-sm-1 " [(bsValue)]="fechaHasta"></em>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
          <button class="btn btn-oval btn-sm ml-2 " (click)="creaSolicitudFolio()" type="button">
            Nuevo
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-oval btn-sm ml-2 " (click)="buscaFolios()" type="button">
            Buscar
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- SEGUNDA COLUMNA -->
      <div class="row doc-row mt-2">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <!-- Cantidad desde-->
          <label class="col-sm-1 control-label lh-11 documento-label">Cantidad desde</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="date" formControlName="cantidadDesde" name="cantidadDesde" id="cantidadDesde" type="text"
              class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <span #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker class="fa fa-search facturas col-sm-1 "
            [(bsValue)]="cantidadDesde"></span>

          <!-- Cantidad hasta-->
          <label class="col-sm-1 control-label lh-11 documento-label">Cantidad hasta</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="date" formControlName="cantidadHasta" name="cantidadHasta" id="cantidadHasta" type="text"
              class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <em #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker class="fa fa-search facturas col-sm-1 " [(bsValue)]="cantidadHasta"></em>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <!-- tipo documento -->
          <label class="col-sm-1 control-label lh-11 documento-label">Tipo</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control pv-0" formControlName="tipoFactura" name="tipoFactura">
              <option *ngFor="let tipofactura of tiposfacturas" [value]="tipofactura.par_codparametro01">
                {{tipofactura.par_deslargo01}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
```

and this is how they are declared in the .ts file:

```
  constructor( ) {
    this.forma = new FormGroup({
      fechaDesde: new FormControl(''),
      fechaHasta: new FormControl(''),
      cantidadHasta: new FormControl(''),
      cantidadDesde: new FormControl(''),
      tipoFactura: new FormControl('')
    });
  }
```

I can't make them pass the test and I don't know why.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: has you import ReactiveFormsModule in the module.ts at which the component are declared?

Answer (score 1):

```
forma = new FormGroup({
    fechaDesde: new FormControl(''),
    fechaHasta: new FormControl(''),
    cantidadHasta: new FormControl(''),
    cantidadDesde: new FormControl(''),
    tipoFactura: new FormControl('')
});

constructor( ) {}
```

Please try it.

Answer (score 1):

`ng build --prod` should work if there is no build issue and it's not related to the reactive form.

Please check this discussion if that works.
[Angular reactive form binding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53739013/angular-reactive-form-binding-not-working)